# What is the default CallBack URL in manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

We have projects using the [manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) GitHub project to do our OIDC flows.

In the Authorization Code Flow, after the User logs in at the IDP, the IDP calls a url from the application to pass it the code (and session).

**What is the default value that `angular-oauth2-oidc` is listening at for this?**

(In case you wonder why I need this, it is so I can configure my IDP to expect that value.  If it gets a callback url that is not expected, then it blocks the callback.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure `redirectUri`](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/classes/AuthConfig.html#redirectUri) to determine what place in your application is used for this. Its default value is `''`, [I tend to change this to `redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'`](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/f94887971dbf6c9269a6b43e647c95861428c3f7/src/app/core/auth-config.ts#L7) myself.